# Set Object Variables Within Service Method

Tags: java, variables, rx-java

I have a couple domain objects, Message and Contact:

```
public class Contact {
    String name;
}

public class Message {
    String body;
    Contact contact;
}
```

I'm populating a list of `Message` and showing them the user. Contact info for each of the Messages is retrieved asynchronously, and then the list is updated. This is basically how I have it set up:

```
listAdapter.setDataSet(listOfMessages);

for (Message message : listOfMessages) {
    fetchContactDetails(message);
}

...

fetchContactDetails(Message message) {
    contactService
        .fetchContactDetails(listOfMessages)
        .subscribeOn... // observe, etc
        .observe(new Observable<Contact>() {
            onNext(Contact contact) {
                message.setContact(contact);
                list.notifyChanged(message);
            }
        });
```

This feels like a lot of code, given that I could instead just update each `Message` `Contact` within the service function `contactService.fetchContactDetails`. On the contrary, it feels unclean to use a service method to modify the object passed in without returning anything.

Is it a bad practice to use a service function to update a Object passed in as an argument, without returning anything?

Comment: The only thing that I would add is that you should call notifyChanged once, after all the messages have contacts; this will speed up the UI as it needs to update just once.

Comment: what it is the .obesrve() ? and the new Observable ? I would expect to subscribe

Answer (score 0):

> Is it a bad practice to use a service function to update a Object passed in as an argument, without returning anything?

No, you can implement `void` method `Observable`, by using `Completable`, but in your case you will still need to update the UI on the main thread, so you will subscribe and handle the `onNext` on mainThread (by adding `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())`).
So in this case your method not seems to be pure `void` method that returns nothing, but method that updated some data and return it to the UI for processing.

So, I think it is more general architectural question, of how to separate the code right. I would defiantly gather the model/domain logic together in separate `Observable`, and let the UI/presentation handle the just the UI updates.

BTW, you can loop more elegantly with Rx using `from()` and `flatMap()`

```
Observable.from(listOfMessages)
   .flatMap(msg -> contactService.fetchContactDetails(msg))
```

then you can have control on the enitre process, like do something when all updates done, or limit the parallelism or whatever.